# How to join MongoDB collection with string[] on collection with string using Linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, .net-core

I am trying to join two collections. I managed to join the two properly where the joining parts are equivalent in type - but that's not the goal. The difficulty occurs since i have a list of strings (id's) in one of the collections, and i want to replace each string in that list with an object of the other collection which is a collection of users defined as:

```
public string name { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string _id { get; set; }
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

I have two types of meetings where i want to insert the users to the one replacing the strings hence it's a DTO.

```
public class MeetingBase : ModelBase
    {
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public string facilitator { get; set; }
        public string topic { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime meetingDate { get; set; }

    }

public class Meeting : MeetingBase
    {
        public List<string> attendees { get; set; }
    }

public class MeetingDTO : MeetingBase
    {
        public List<User> attendees { get; set; }
    }
```

As said, i want to join the collection og `Meeting` with the collection of `users`, resulting in a collection of `MeetingDTO`'s

So far, my best attempt is this:

```
public async Task<List<MeetingDTO>> getMeetingDtos(string userid)
        {
            var userCollection = _userDataManager.GetDataContext().MongoCollection;
            var meetingCollection = _meetingDataManager.GetDataContext().MongoCollection;

            var query = from m in meetingCollection.AsQueryable()
                where (m.createdBy == userid)
                from attendee in m.attendees
                join u in userCollection.AsQueryable() on attendee equals u._id into meetingusers
                select new MeetingDTO()
                {
                    _id = m._id,
                    IsDeleted = m.IsDeleted,
                    attendees = meetingusers.ToList(),
                    address = m.address,
                    city = m.city,
                    country = m.country,
                    createdBy = m.createdBy,
                    facilitator = m.facilitator,
                    meetingDate = m.meetingDate,
                    RoomNumber = m.RoomNumber,
                    topic = m.topic

                };

            var result = query.ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

However, this attempt gives the following run-time exception `System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support {document}.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with the `.Aggregate()` interface of the collection like so:

```cs
    var meetingDTOs = meetingCollection.Aggregate()
                        .Match(m => m.createdBy == userid)
                        .Lookup<Meeting, User, MeetingDTO>(
                            userCollection,
                            m => m.attendees,
                            u => u.Id,
                            dto => dto.attendees)
                        .ToList();
```

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class User : Entity
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeetingBase : Entity
    {
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public string topic { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meeting : MeetingBase
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public List<string> attendees { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeetingDTO : MeetingBase
    {
        public List<User> attendees { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            var user1 = new User { name = "user one" };
            var user2 = new User { name = "user two" };
            new[] { user1, user2 }.Save();

            var meeting = new Meeting
            {
                attendees = new List<string> { user1.ID, user2.ID },
                createdBy = "god",
                topic = "corona beer"
            };
            meeting.Save();

            var meetingDTOs = DB.Fluent<Meeting>()
                                .Match(m => m.createdBy == "god")
                                .Lookup<Meeting, User, MeetingDTO>(
                                    DB.Collection<User>(),
                                    m => m.attendees,
                                    u => u.ID,
                                    dto => dto.attendees)
                                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndersMøllerHansen my pleasure. wish mongodb c# team does a better job at documentation ;-)